# Add html attribute in checkout street address

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I need to add maxLength attribute to street line 1 and 2 in the Magento 2 check out page. How can I do this Magento 2? Can this be done from theme without creating a new module?

Comment: you can add  maxlength="10" for input box like `<input title="Street Address" name="billing[street][]" id="billing:street1" value="" class="input-text  required-entry" type="text"  maxlength="10" >`

Comment: Hi @GopalPatel which files  need to override as per your comment?

Comment: look at my answer, it is a best practise then the accepted one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by overriding the input template in your theme. Create the file `<theme_dir>/Magento_Ui/web/templates/form/element/input.html` with this contents:

```
<input class="input-text" type="text" data-bind="
    value: value,
    valueUpdate: 'keyup',
    hasFocus: focused,
    attr: {
        name: inputName,
        placeholder: placeholder,
        'aria-describedby': noticeId,
        id: uid,
        disabled: disabled,
        maxlength: inputName.slice(0,6) === 'street' ? 30 : 'none'
    }" />
```

Replace the number 30 with whatever you want the max length to be. You then need to delete the contents of `pub/static` and `var/view_preprocessed` and possibly clear your browser cache to make sure the new template gets loaded.

Note: this could create problems if there are other inputs on the site using the name 'street' where you don't want to have a max length. To change the template for just the street inputs on checkout page would require creating a module.

Comment: This does exactly what I have asked for. Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: It's not working for me in Magento 2 CE Version 2.1.2. I'm in Production Mode. I need to apply this on Checkout Page

Comment: In production mode you would need to re-deploy static content. One reason why you shouldn't develop in production mode.

Comment: Finally it works in Developer Mode. But it's not working in Production Mode :(

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is absolutly a bad patch. For example, if you have another input field named **streetCustom** it also takes the maxlength attribute.

Anyway, i think that you have to modify the php file where the input validation attributes are generated, so as well as avoid any problems, you also understand how it works.

The php file is `Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\AttributeMerger` and the method used to generate street input field is `getMultilineFieldConfig`, beacause street field is defined as **multiline** from `eav_attribute` db table.

Here you could add

```
...
// change max_length validation only for street attribute
if ( $attributeCode == 'street' ) {

    $line['validation']['max_text_length'] = 10;

}

// before
$lines[] = $line;
...
```

Now you have a proper and working validation in magento2 style for all lines of your street input field.

**N.B.**: change directly magento core files is a bad practice. If you considerer to use a best practice here i recommend to create a custom module and [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148951/magento-2-how-to-set-max-length-for-street-address) you could take some hints.