# Magento 2: How to set Max Length for Street Address?

Tags: magento2, checkout, customer, custom, form-validation

I would like to set Max Length for Customer's Street Address 1 to 50 Characters & Street Address 2 to 100 Characters.

[image]

Changes will be applied on Frontend only, where we can find Street Address.

Last is to override page.

How to achieve this?

Comment: duplicate of http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/143337/add-html-attribute-in-checkout-street-address/143352#143352

Comment: Hi @AaronAllen not working for me :(

Comment: @AnkitShah Great you found your own solution. I wonder this can be done with checkout_index_index.xml? In this file you can set the max length for input fields on checkout page.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally I Got Solution by creating new Module :)

Referce Post: [Magento 2 - How to affect street address in checkout forms with layout xml/ui arguments](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113797/magento-2-how-to-affect-street-address-in-checkout-forms-with-layout-xml-ui-ar)

**magento\app\code\Custom\Checkout\registration.php**

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
        \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Custom_Checkout', __DIR__
);
```

**magento\app\code\Custom\Checkout\etc\module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Custom_Checkout" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

**magento\app\code\Custom\Checkout\etc\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="Custom_Checkout" type="Custom\Checkout\Block\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="100"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**magento\app\code\Custom\Checkout\Block\LayoutProcessor.php**

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Checkout\Block;

class LayoutProcessor {

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(
    \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject, array $jsLayout
    ) {
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
                ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['street'] = [
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/group',
            'label' => __('Street Address'),
            'required' => true,
            'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.street',
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'sortOrder' => 60,
            'type' => 'group',
            'children' => [
                    [
                    'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                    'config' => [
                        'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                        'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                        'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input'
                    ],
                    'dataScope' => '0',
                    'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                    'validation' => ['required-entry' => true, "min_text_len‌​gth" => 1, "max_text_length" => 50],
                ],
                    [
                    'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                    'config' => [
                        'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                        'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                        'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input'
                    ],
                    'dataScope' => '1',
                    'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                    'validation' => ['required-entry' => false, "min_text_len‌​gth" => 1, "max_text_length" => 50],
                ]
            ]
        ];
        return $jsLayout;
    }

}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Its great that you have find the file in which you have to edit. I want you to find the file on your own thats why i have not gave the reply on that answer. Because directory structure of magento is simple to understand and by small research you can get your file.

Comment: very nice, but so you have limited the number of street lines to 2. i think is better mantein original loop and set max_length with a variable in base of loop index, so if a user set more of 2 lines could use anyway this code.

Comment: @AnkitShah I'm trying to do the same to set a Max Length for the input fields on checkout page. In your LayoutProcessor.php, how is this function afterProcess being called? This function doesn't exist in /Magento/module-checkout/Block/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To build on the solution from @Jackson, the plugin code can be simplified and implemented to cover however many address lines have been configured.

```
public function afterProcess(
    \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
    array $jsLayout) 
{

    // Restrict street address length
    foreach ($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']
                      ['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
                      ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']
                      ['street']['children'] as $line) {
        $line['validation']['max_text_length'] = 50;
    }

    return $jsLayout;
}
```

Note that while this is allegedly targeting the shipping address it also applies to the billing address on the checkout, at least on our site using BSS Commerce One Step Checkout it does. May not be the case for whatever checkout you're using so you'll need to investigate (debug) the unfeasibly complicated $jsLayout provided to see if billing also needs to be amended.

Bring on Hyva!

Answer (score 0):

try to set `maxLength`

```
<input type="text" name="federal" maxlength="10"  value="" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Federal Tax ID (EIN)') ?>" class="input-text" id="federal" data-validate="{required:true, 'federal':true}">
```

Comment: Already know above thing. This is not what i'm looking for. Which template file needs to override?. Would like to display message to user that "Max Length is 50 Characters" for Line 1 & Same for Line 2 with "Max Length is 100 Characters"

Answer (score 0):

You can set the max length and/or many more other validation quite easily by just adding them to the correct element in the layout xml for the input form you want to affect.

```
<item name="street" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
        <!-- Classes for data validation: -->
        <item name="min_text_length" xsi:type="number">1</item>
        <item name="max_text_length" xsi:type="number">50</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

You can check out my comment [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/250669/73203) where you can find a list of some other available validations

Comment: This would be a better answer if you actually showed how to accomplish this to answer the question posed i.e.  what XML would need to be overridden to add this validation. where would it go?