# Magento 2: How to add Class on Checkout Page?

Tags: magento2, checkout, customer, custom-options, validation

I would like to add below class on "Firstname"

```
class="validate-length minimum-length-10 maximum-length-100"
```

It should be applied on Checkout Page.

```
domain.com/checkout/
```

Need to override file `magento\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\onepage.phtml`?

Comment: Have you got answer of this question?

Comment: No @Rakesh. I think http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148951/magento-2-how-to-set-max-length-for-street-address Can apply class here Right ?

Comment: Yes so i have think you have did for checkout, may be try with same method for above case.

Comment: Yes @Rakesh It's Gonna Work :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add that validation using overriding **\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor** using plugin.

**etc/di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
    <plugin name="custom_field" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Checkout\Model\Checkout\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="100"/>
</type>
```

**LayoutProcessor.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Checkout\Model\Checkout\LayoutProcessor;
class LayoutProcessor
{
/**
 * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
 * @param array $jsLayout
 * @return array
 */
public function afterProcess(
    \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
    array  $jsLayout
) {
    /*$jsLayout you can set your field that you want to customize*/
    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
    ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['postcode'] = [
        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
        'config' => [
            'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
            'template' => 'ui/form/field',
            'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input',
            'options' => [],
        ],
        'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.postcode',
        'label' => 'Zip/Postal Code',
        'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
        'visible' => true,
        'validation' => ['required-entry' => true], //Here you can add you validation
    ];
    return $jsLayout;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Chirag. I already posted that link in comments

Comment: can you pass class name or ID so i can add css
is that possible