# Magento2 - How to trigger onchange event on Country/region in Shipping Address

Tags: magento2, checkout

**I want to customize checkout page where I can add my jQuery on change event on country, region field,**

So Whenever Customer change field like `country,region` option few rest of fields like `city, zip/Post Code, Address and province change`.

Answer (score 8):

Create `requirejs-config.js` in your `Namespace/Module/view/frontend`

```
var config = {
    'config': {
        'mixins': {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information': {
                'Namespace_Module/js/action/set-shipping-information-mixin': true
            } 
        }
    }
};
```

**some quote were missing above caused errors**

then create `set-shipping-information-mixin.js` in `Namespace/Module/view/frontend/web/js/action/`

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-service',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-registry',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-processor/customer-address',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-processor/new-address',
], function ($, wrapper, quote, shippingService, rateRegistry, customerAddressProcessor, newAddressProcessor) {

    $(document).on('change',"[name='country']",function(){
       //for country
    });

    $(document).on('change',"[name='region_id']",function(){
       //for province or region
    });
});
```

don't forget to run `setup upgrade` and `static content deploy`

Comment: above code throws an error "mixin is not a function"

Comment: @Dsmagento i am also getting same issue have u resolved this?

Comment: @NagarajuKasa add quotes around 'config' and 'mixins'

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution for mixins JS issue. This worked for me.

Create `requirejs-config.js` in your `Namespace/Module/view/base/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    'config': {
        'mixins': {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information': {
                'Ktpl_CheckoutWarning/js/hook': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

then create set-shipping-information-mixin.js in `Namespace/Module/view/base/web/js/hook.js`

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';
    console.log("Called this Hook.");

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('change', "[name='country_id']", function () {
            alert("Hi");
        });
    });

    return function (targetModule) {
        targetModule.crazyPropertyAddedHere = 'yes';
        return targetModule;
    };
});
```

Run Setup upgrade and content-deploy command. Let me know if you face any other. To verify this Check-in console it will show "Called this Hook."

Thanks to this [blog](https://alanstorm.com/the-curious-case-of-magento-2-mixins/)

Comment: can you please look into https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/233106/magento-2-checkout-page-how-to-get-city-id-from-selected-shipping-addresses

Comment: this fires on initial load. How can I skip the change event on initial page load? I tried to wrap in inside $(window).load(function() but without success. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to add you custom class in the field you want read the event.
refer this for adding the custom class/id

1.[Change the checkout form field classes and names](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/161780/change-the-checkout-form-field-classes-and-names).

OR

2. [Magento 2: How to add Class on Checkout Page?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149118/magento-2-how-to-add-class-on-checkout-page)

After that you can write you logic in any of the checkout steps js file (if jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

Actually this should work by default if you have more then one shipping method, if you are using table rates and you want to work by country only using the table rates you can do a trick.

Add the free shipping method in admin, and set the "Minimum Order Amount" with a very large number, ex 9999999.

And now it works!