# Onchange event in while country change in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, event-observer, checkout-page, country-regions

I need to change `city` field as a `select field` while change `country` name as `India`. otherwise, it shows text field.

I [follow](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/175806/magento2-how-to-trigger-onchange-event-on-country-region-in-shipping-address)  this link use @Idham Choudry answer, but its throw `Uncaught TypeError: mixing is not a function`

**what I did:**

Create `requirejs-config.js` in your `Namespace/Module/view/frontend`

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information': {
                'Namespace_Module/js/action/set-shipping-information-mixin': true
            } 
        }
    }
};
```

then create `set-shipping-information-mixin.js` in `Namespace/Module/view/frontend/web/js/action/`

```
        define([
        'jquery',
        'mage/utils/wrapper',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-service',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-registry',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-processor/customer-address',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-processor/new-address',
    ], function ($, wrapper, quote, shippingService, rateRegistry, customerAddressProcessor, newAddressProcessor) {

        $(document).on('change',"[name='country_id']",function(){
           //for country
           alert("country Changed");
           console.log("country Changed");
        });

        $(document).on('change',"[name='region_id']",function(){
           //for province or region
           alert("state Changed");
           console.log("state Changed");
        });
    });
```

Suggest me,

1. How Magento 2 did, while `country` change, then That Country related State is there in `directory_country_region` table means, its change `select` field, otherwise, its show `text` filed and which file handle this functionality, I need to do same thing to in my case.
2. what's error in my code and how to fix this.

**Note:** I am using Magento 2.1.7

Comment: have you found any solution for this? If any, please share here.

Comment: Hello @Yudi, I posted an answer for same.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution for mixins JS issue. This worked for me.

Create `requirejs-config.js` in your `Namespace/Module/view/base/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    'config': {
        'mixins': {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information': {
                'Ktpl_CheckoutWarning/js/hook': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

then create set-shipping-information-mixin.js in `Namespace/Module/view/base/web/js/hook.js`

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';
    console.log("Called this Hook.");

    $(document).on('change',"[name='country_id']",function(){
        alert("Hi");
    });

    return function (targetModule) {
        targetModule.crazyPropertyAddedHere = 'yes';
        return targetModule;
    };
});
```

Run Setup upgrade and content-deploy command. Let me know if you face any other. To verify this Check-in console it will show "Called this Hook."

Thanks to this [blog](https://alanstorm.com/the-curious-case-of-magento-2-mixins/).

You can check this reference [also](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/175806/magento2-how-to-trigger-onchange-event-on-country-region-in-shipping-address).

Answer (score 2):

You can include the quote as a dependency in your mixin (or new component) and subscribe on the shippingAddress like this:

```
define([
    'ko',
    'uiElement',
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'domReady!',
], function (ko, Component, $, quote) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({

        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            quote.shippingAddress.subscribe(this.shippingAddressObserver.bind(this));
        },

        shippingAddressObserver: function (address) {
            if(address.countryId == "IN") { //Not sure what the country ID of india is
                // Your logic
            }
        }
    });
```