# How do i restrict the user to only using 8 numbers in the telephone field on checkout?

Tags: magento-2.1, magento2.3

I am trying to force the user to use numbers in the field limiting them to 9 numbers (no more and no less). I've found that that the XML file path for the checkout page is
 `*\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\layout\checkout_index_index.xml` and the code related to the phone is as follows:

```
 <item name="min_text_length" xsi:type="number">11</item>
 <item name="max_text_length" xsi:type="number">11</item>
 <item name="validate-number" xsi:type="number">1</item>
```

And now i want to add a validation similar to the min_max_length that would refuse to accept any further input past **9 numbers**

Comment: Have you seen this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/150984/70343

Comment: @DominicXigen Thank you for responding, Yes, i checked this yesterday but i wanted to rule out the possibility that it cant be done from WITHIN the xml file. If said possibility is ruled out then ill repost my question asking for clarification on how i can do it using JS because most Q&As are working with older version of magento (im currently using 2.3.5). Do you have any idea if it can be done from within the XML like "min_text_length"?