# Magento 2 manipulate shipping address fields in chekout via knockout.js

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout

i already know how to add new field to shipping address form in checkout, but i need to modify the behavior of some fields. For example:

- there is a checkbox "Deliver to Packing station";
- if checkbox is selected, "street" fields becomes hidden and not required, but 2 new fields ("Packing station #" and "Post #") becomes visible and required.

I completely stuck with that. I'm not very familiar with knockout, just have read some lessons on it.
Any help/ideas? (except "go learn knockout.js" :))

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148951/magento-2-how-to-set-max-length-for-street-address/

Comment: not really what i need. I know how to change form via layout. I need to change it dynamically via js

Comment: @Styopchik , did you find the solution. Please can you share it here.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution, here is an example:

```
define([
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/single-checkbox'
], function (AbstractField) {
    'use strict';

    return AbstractField.extend({
        defaults: {
            modules: {
                packing_station_nr: '${ $.parentName }.packing_station_nr',
                post_nr: '${ $.parentName }.post_nr'
            }
        },

        onCheckedChanged: function () {
            this.packing_station_nr().visible(this.checked());
            this.post_nr().visible(this.checked());
            this._super()
        }


    });
});
```

P.S. this code only toggles fields visibility. Make fields required by default. If field is not visible, validator skips it's validation.