# Checkout page street address filed custom validation

Tags: magento2

How can I set min_text_length of street address field on the checkout page to 2?
I have referred the below link
[Magento 2: How to set Max Length for Street Address?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148951/magento-2-how-to-set-max-length-for-street-address)
but it doesn't work!

Comment: Can you provide more informations? Code example . Thank you

Comment: @sami23 you can refer to the link I've mentioned

Comment: I just took a look . You should provide us your code to can help you. Thank you

Comment: Below is the code snippet from LayoutProcessor.php in custom checkout module:

Comment: [
                    'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                    'config' => [
                        'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                        'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                        'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input'
                    ],
                    'dataScope' => '0',
                    'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                    'validation' => ['required-entry' => true, "min_text_len‌​gth" => 10, "max_text_length" => 15],
                ],

Comment: plz put  all the code of your file.