# Add html attribute maxlength to street input field in magento 2 checkout page

Tags: checkout, magento2.3, street-address

How to add new html attribute maxlength="10" to street input field on shipping address form.

Thanks

Comment: do you want  all Street Address input feilds ?

Comment: yes for 2 street fields

Comment: You can check with this answer, [Adding maxlength to street](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148951/magento-2-how-to-set-max-length-for-street-address#149139)

Comment: @aravind i want html attribut maxlength not validation max_lenght

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this with below code

```
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
    jQuery(document).ready( function() {
        var existConditionZero = setInterval(function() {
            if (jQuery("input[name='street[0]']").length > 0) { 
                clearInterval(existConditionZero);
                runMyFunctionZero();
            }
        }, 100);
        function runMyFunctionZero(){
            jQuery('input[name="street[0]"]').attr("maxlength","10");
        }
    });
});

require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
    jQuery(document).ready( function() {
        var existConditionOne = setInterval(function() {
            if (jQuery("input[name='street[1]']").length > 0) { 
                clearInterval(existConditionOne);
                runMyFunctionOne();
            }
        }, 100);
        function runMyFunctionOne(){
            jQuery('input[name="street[1]"]').attr("maxlength","10");
        }
    });
});
```