# How to add maxlength to street address column in backend via data patch

Tags: magento2

I would appreciate any help on how to add maxlength to street address column in backend via data patch

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this using a data patch. Street address is a multiline attribute:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-multiline.html

If you check in customer_address_entity, column street you will see it is a text with 65535 characters.

I would recommend using frontend validation for this.
You can have a look here for more information:

[Magento 2: How to set Max Length for Street Address?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148951/magento-2-how-to-set-max-length-for-street-address)

Comment: Thanks for the contribution I used data patch to solve that . I understand that its a multi line attribute but that was the request. It was also enforced on the frontend so its all good. Its a headless proj by the way