# Magento 2 how can i limit character (max.40) for shipping Address street in Checkout?

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping

We have the Problem, some Customers add a too long Shipping Address Street.
How can i limit this in Checkout Step 1?

Comment: Hi @FloWord, Do you want this for checkout page only or everywhere?

Comment: Hi @RamkishanSuthar for Adresse Street Field over All or what is easier?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2: How to set Max Length for Street Address?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148951/magento-2-how-to-set-max-length-for-street-address)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add html attribute in checkout street address](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/143337/add-html-attribute-in-checkout-street-address)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by making a new module where you will have to overwrite `LayoutProcessor.php` file.

Please checkout this link for further clarification
[Magento 2: How to set Max Length for Street Address?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148951/magento-2-how-to-set-max-length-for-street-address)

Comment: Please don't just link a question that does not have a suitable answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to change the customer street address length, you can just manage the attribute on the back-office's customer address attribute :

[image: Customer stress address attribute]